# HttpRequestValidationException when signing out

Tags: asp.net

On my master page I have a LoginStatus control which allows users to sign out of the application.  The problem is that if within the page, the user enters invalid data like "<test>" and then, *without* submitting the form, the user clicks "sign out" a HttpRequestValidationException is raised.  When the user clicks "sign out", any pending input is going to be discarded anyway.

What I ended up doing is using javascript to call reset() on the form when the user clicks "sign out."  This circumvents the HttpRequestValidationException problem adequately.  Does anyone have other suggestions for how to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is pretty good.  Your only other option I can think of would be to turn off page validation in the @Page directive for that particular page.  But then of course you are losing the security that provides.

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" ... %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Bryan.  I'm aware of the option you describe.  Because the LoginStatus control exists on the master page, turning off page validation would mean turning page validation off for the entire site which isn't a viable alternative.